# Get block title from hook block view

Tags: blocks, hooks

I create blog programmatically and I want to show  title block.

This is not working:

```
  'header' =>  array(
                    '#prefix' => '<p>',
                    '#suffix' => '</p>',
                    '#markup' =>  $block->subject,
               ),
```

Or better to create new field via ***hook_block_configure***?
Maybe exist way to find title from DB?

Comment: Drupal 7 or Drupal 8? Kindly specific version before asking any question.

Comment: @AAjayReddy Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'name-block_1'); 
 $title = $block->title;
 $content = render($block['content']);
```